# Some sites fail to load on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, connection

When I try to go to Office 365 I get an error.

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at https://www.office.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_FAILED
```

Other sites such as google.com can be accessed.
I have another laptop which can access the site it from the same LAN network so the issue is with the computer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of things, and finally managed to fix the issue by running these commands as administrator, and then restarting the computer:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int ip reset
```

I found the instructions from [here](https://blackdesert.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000267565--Procedure-How-to-flush-your-DNS-reset-your-TCP-IP)